# Making website compatible with IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, css

All,

On my website:

[www.coutallure.com](http://www.coutallure.com)

Dont care about IE6 but am trying to make my website compatible with IE7.

I have followed the advice online, however, still the page seems unwilling to bend to the rules of its IE7 master browser. In resignation, Ive given up trying to take sides and would like both parties to just get along, which seems to be asking a bit too much.

1) At the bottom of the page is 'bottom bar', I am using 'display: inline-block' to spread the three main 'li' items within the div. However, IE7 doesnt like 'inline-block' so used the advice of inserting '*display', '_height' & 'zoom' values as per:

http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

however, the 'li' in 'bottom bar' are still not sitting correctly.

Any advice on getting everything to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.coutallure.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), and fix the structural errors. You have for example double body tags, duplicate id:s and unmatched div elements.

There is no standard (yet) for how to treat incorrect markup, so browsers will react very differently to it.

Comment: thanks for the obvious pointer. I had somehow totally forgotten to validate the markup. Alls done, however the problem persists... am going to create a new thread about the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `inline-block` in IE7 by giving `display:inline` and `zoom:1` to element style.